# Woocomerce direct checkout URL with GA4 query

Tags: woocommerce, google-analytics

i set up a cross-domain tracking on my site.
so when ever a external domain is clicked a ?_gl query is passed.
But when i click woocommerce direct checkout urls  the ?gl query is missing & most probably that's because woocommerce strip all query strings after add to cart.

You can check it live here : https://www.arhantayoga.nl/test/

is there any way i can keep the ?gl query on the checkout?

Answer (score 0):

I tried from your link and the `_gl` parameter is passed either way.